# reference with eqnarray

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, labels, bakoma

I'm trying to reference some equations in my latex file and I keep getting `??` as a response. At first, I used `eqnarray`, but I also tried to use `equation` and `align`.

This is the code I'm using now:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
    \label{true1}
    \hspace{1cm} \int_{0}^{K} x f(x|1) dx+(1-F(K|1))K &\geq &1-A,\\
    \label{true2}
    \hspace{1cm} \int_{K}^{\infty}(x-K)(f(x|1)-f(x|0))dx &\geq & c.
\end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: Do you compile two-times? Off-topic: instead of `eqnarray` is better to use `align` defined in `amsmath` package.

Comment: Never use `eqnarray`, but how exactly are you adding the references?

Answer (score 3):

This works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{eqnarray}
        \label{true1}
        \hspace{1cm} \int_{0}^{K} x f(x|1) dx+(1-F(K|1))K &\geq &1-A,\\
        \label{true2}
        \hspace{1cm} \int_{K}^{\infty}(x-K)(f(x|1)-f(x|0))dx &\geq & c.
    \end{eqnarray}

    Equations (\ref{true1}) and (\ref{true2})
\end{document}
```

(but `align` is preferable to `eqnarray` and `\eqref` or `\cref` to `(\ref)`)

Comment: you should mentioned, that references appear after second compilation of code (as I mentioned/asked in my comment). Before you see (famous) `??` ...

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing. Sorry I wasn't more specific. Nevertheless I still not getting the references properly.

Comment: @FelipeDamasceno if you ran latex _twice_ on a document and the references do not show, fix the example in your question to be a complete small document that shows the problem (like JPi's example here). People can not debug code they can not see.

Comment: @Zarko: you'd already mentioned that!  ;-)

Comment: I'm using Bakoma Tex, thus the compilation is automatic. Am I thinking it wrongly?

Comment: Does my code give you ?? also?